# Mercurial tries to access svn root while converting

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

Im trying to migrate SVN repository to Mercurial.
When i try to convert SVN repository using the below command: 
C:>hg convert https://remote.server.com/svn/main/components/component1/trunk .

i get this error:
**abort: log stream exception '("access to 'https://remote.server.com/svn/main' forbidden", 175013)'**

I do have access to the trunk [https://remote.server.com/svn/main/components/component1/trunk].

But i do not have access to the root [https://remote.server.com/svn/main]

Why is mercurial trying to access the root instead of trunk while converting. Please assist.

Here are the versions of the software i have:

Tortoise hg: 2.10
Subversion: 1.6.16

Comment: I used debug to see whats going on: and hg convert tries to reparent to the root. 

 C:>hg -v --debug convert https://remote.server.com/svn/main/components/component1/trunk
reparent to https://remote.server.com/svn/main
abort: log stream exception '("access to 'https://remote.server.com/svn/main' forbidden", 175013)'

Couldnt understand why hg convert reparent to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Convert recommends using svnsync to sync the svn repo locally before converting, and it's really good advice.  It's more reliable and lets you retry/re-import more quickly.